# What are these Node.js and javascript frameworks and what do they do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, ember.js, dojo

Can anyone explain or provide a link or a video that explains what all of these are and why I should care?**  How do they fit into the big picture?  How would they fit together if used together?

I'm not looking for your opinion; I'm looking for some concise description of what problems each one solves, and how can I understand what to use for what.  This really should be out there some place, but it isn't so easy to find.  Please don't over-simplify descriptions.

- Backbonejs
- Angularjs
- Jasmine
- Mocha
- Dojo
- YUI
- Scriptaculous
- Ember.js
- Knockout
- Grunt
- Bower
- Yeoman
- Requirejs

Comment: It's not enough just to read a few books and learn the basics. If you are attempting to become a professional in these technologies, you should really spend some time and build something, using a small subset of the frameworks you've listed. I would group them into similar categories (Node is a server-side language, jQuery/Dojo/YUI are browser javascript frameworks, etc.) and really dig in. You can spend months or years on just one of these and still learn new things about them, that's the beauty and complexity of technology in general.

Comment: I think your downvote on my question was uncalled for.  In addition, while what you said has some truth, it really doesn't address where to begin.  It comes off as arrogant and is simply not helpful.  Thank you, but I'm going to look for some other info.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. Your question was most likely downvoted (by someone else) because it is what Stack Overflow calls a "Shopping Question," which is a question that is very open ended (like asking for a recommendation for something), and not a question that can have an answer that is anything but an opinion.

Comment: I've reformed the question to be more clear about what I'm after.  Maybe that will help.  I wasn't "shopping" or anything.  I'm not after opinions.  I just want some useful information because when all I was ever aware of for years is jQuery & Node.js, the world suddenly makes me feel a lot smaller.  I want clued in to what the hype is all about here.

Comment: I actually wouldn't mind seeing this question answered, so I hope it can be reopened once it has been edited.

Comment: I've re-worded it, but it is still closed.  How do I get it re-opened?!

Comment: Although I disagree that this question is opinion-based (at least not anymore after the edit), unfortunately the original premise is still way too broad because it asks about upwards of a dozen different technologies. On Stack Overflow we prefer questions that are narrowed down to a single specific topic, as opposed to asking for information on a number of different technologies (whether or not they are related in some way).

Comment: No, most of these are in some way very closely related to Node.js.  Being that nearly anyone well versed in Node development should understand what most of this is, I expect there to be an answer.  Even at this point I could answer some of this, but not nearly enough.  It's just that nobody can seem to see the relevance of the need for the question to be answered.  It's pretty frustrating actually. It's almost as if asking a ton of scifi geeks "what is star trek, star wars, star gate, etc etc" and only getting, "read read read..watch and read." uh, excuse me?

Answer (score 1):

**This is how I do it:**

1. Research. Study code. Modify code. Write code. Refactor Code. Repeat.

Start with a simple program that you feel comfortable with. If you spend 5+ hours a day, you'll be fluent in about 8 months. I recommend installing Meteorite, and digging into the smart packages to study code. Best mrt package site: http://atmosphere.meteor.com

**Valuable Resources:**

- http://github.com - Many programs you can download and tinker with from any language
- http://yauh.de/articles/376/best-learning-resources-for-meteorjs - Meteor.js resources
- http://book.mixu.net/node/ - Nice book on Node.js
- http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/ - CSS / Javascript UI framework

That should be a good starting point, but remember you're going to also need to study MongoDB for your databasing. You'll want to use Google Chrome's Developer Tools for debugging and development, so get comfortable with every feature of it.  Stick with coding several hours a day. Even if you get frustrated.  It's the only way to teach yourself. If you can't do that, take a class, or get a tutor.

Comment: I can appreciate where this is coming from, but I still don't feel I'm getting a sense of the broader picture...where these all fit in the scope of node programming, and where I might find lessons on all of these different frameworks.  I used to program for hours a day, but my life is too busy now to allow for that.  Surely there's resources on how to get going on this stuff without having to basically figure it out on my own by tinkering for endless hours.

Comment: Go to Meteor.com download the examples, and follow along with the video on it. That is the quickest way.

Comment: I'm a newbie, this is my take.  The frameworks 'fit' by streamlining programming, they abstract tasks that you would otherwise spend a lot of time coding up in pure javascript.  That includes templates for web pages, page styles, data handling automation.  Frameworks usually adopt a philosophy to programming that guides their choice of abstractions (though 'simplicity'and 'javascript throughout the stack' show up in just about every one).  If you're a newbie it doesn't matter what you use, learn one and _then_ you'll be able to make an informed decision.  So pick any one and go for it.

Comment: Thanks MikeB.  I can gather that much.  What I'm looking for is a frame of reference or something that helps me to know what each one of these do.  Like for Backbone.js it's client-side MVC (or as they call it MV*) I guess.  Angular seems to be more or less similar to Backbone's purpose, but takes a different approach and makes wiring up models to views nearly seamless with hardly any code.  It's that sort of information which would be useful.  Thanks again.

Comment: 5+ hours a day for at most a week or two should make you fluent. Idk how you got 8 months 5+ hours a day, you can make a whole new framework by yourself in that time.

Comment: abden003 - I meant that 60 hours should get him fluent with the framework, and after 8 months, op should understand how to create modules / frameworks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a help for you :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

The rest is learning by doing and don't try to learn everything at once, but rather one by one;-)

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Thank you for that.  I think that's a place to start.  Although I don't oppose buying and reading good books if anybody has any recommendations.